# Binding HTML to the scope in Angular UI popup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using the Angular UI Bootstrap directive to show a popover which functions as a dropdown menu.  If I specify a HTML template for the content (using the attribute popover-template) I can use clickable links which call a function on my directive to change the value.  Now, however, I need to be able to specify options on the fly so I've tried creating the HTML list and passing it to the "popover" attribute in my directive's link function.  This works, in that it displays the HTML in the popover correctly, however the links aren't clickable because they're within a ng-bind-html unsafe container.  I've tried compiling the HTML string I'm passing to the "popover" attribute but it prints [object Object].

Here's my directive:

```
    MyApp.directive('dropDown', ['$compile', function($compile){
return{
    restrict:'EA',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    scope:{
         value : '@',
         options : '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.doSelect = function(option, text){
            alert(option);
        }

    },
    template: '<div>'+
                '<button class="btn btn-dropdown" data-html="true" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-placement="bottom"  popover-trigger="click">'+
                    '{{value}}'+
                '<span class="icon-triangle-down"></span></button>' +       
            '</div>',   

    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.list = '<ul class="dropdown">';
        for (opt in scope.options){
            if(scope.options.hasOwnProperty(opt)){
                scope.list+='<li><a ng-click="doSelect(\''+opt+'\', \''+scope.options[opt]+'\');">'+scope.options[opt]+'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        scope.list += '</ul>';
        var but = elem.find("button");
        var template = $compile(scope.list)(scope);
        //$(but).attr('popover', template);        // prints [object Object] instead of compiled html
        $(but).attr('popover', scope.list);    // prints html not bound to scope and therefore not clickable
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);

    }
}}]);
```

I've created a fiddle to illustrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/CaroD/7B5qB/3/

So: is there any way to compile this HTML so it can interact with the scope, or am I taking a completely wrong approach here?

All suggestions most welcome, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to do not a big directive like that, have you try to use the html-unsafe attribute of the tooltip provider? it gives you the possiblity to put html text into popover and so you surely interact with it.

Comment: Hi,I am using html-unsafe, that's why I can't bind the click event in the HTML.